# about array length in javascript

Tags: javascript

can I give to empty array certain length that, that array will take only that much length of elements.
for example:

```
 var emptyArray = []; // but I need this array takes only 10 elements
 for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
     emptyArray.push(i);
 }
 console.log(emptyArray.length) // I want to see 10
 console.log(emptyArray) // [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: No, but you can check its length before pushing, optionally wrapping that check in a function or object.

Comment: You can define your own object type that acts like an array, but limits its size.

Comment: What is the behavior you want on the 11th push? An error? Silence? Push earlier elements off the other end? All of these are doable, but you need to decide which is correct for your application.

Comment: @Mark_M: Silence – see the example in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```js
function limitedArray(length) {
  return new Proxy([], {
    set: (target, prop, value) => {
      if (Number(prop) < length) {
        target[prop] = value;
      }
      
      return true;
    }
  });
}

var tenArray = limitedArray(10);

for (let i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
  tenArray.push(i);
}

console.log(Array.from(tenArray)); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You can use a different `set` method instead, if you want it to throw an error when the array’s length is about to be exceeded:

```
set: (target, prop, value) => {
  if(!isNaN(prop) && Number(prop) >= length){
    return false;
  }

  if (Number(prop) < length) {
    target[prop] = value;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Note though, that handling deletion of elements requires a bit more work.

Comment: Depends on where the code is being used though right?  I don't think you can use transpiling or polyfilling for Proxy.

Comment: Proxy does not have Internet Explorer support right? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Answer (score 3):

You can try Object.seal(). Note that in this example, I'm not using push() since that will throw an error, but assigning values since the values in the fixed length Array are mutable

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal

```js
var emptyArray = new Array(10).fill(0);

Object.seal(emptyArray);

 for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
     emptyArray[i] = i;
 }
 console.log(emptyArray.length) // I want to see 10
 console.log(emptyArray) // [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: This would be elegant, but it’ll throw in strict mode.

Answer (score -1):

Not directly as you want, however you can have something similar :

```
var emptyArray = Array.from({length:50}, (v,i) => undefined);
for(let i=0; i<emptyArray;i++){
    emptyArray.push(i);
}
```

Basically you set up your array with undefined values with a certain length, and then loop until you reach the length.